# Wrong method is called

Tags: c#

*The below code might look odd in functionality. This is because this is a simplified presentation of something bigger.*

I have a `class` named **Person** and the person has 1 `property` named **string Name**.

In another `class` named **ClassRoom** I have the following `constructors`:

```
protected ClassRoom() { }

public ClassRoom(Person person) : this(person == null ? null : person, person.Name) { }

public ClassRoom(Person person, string name)
{
    // Possible NullReferenceException which is not that important because it can be anticipated on.
    person.Name = name;
}
```

My goal with `ClassRoom(Person person)` is that, if the **Person** is null, `ClassRoom()` is called and if it's not null `ClassRoom(Person person, string name)` is called.

To make sure this is working I wrote a **Unit Test**. When I do `new ClassRoom(null)` in my test, a **NullReferenceException** is thrown in `ClassRoom(Person person, string name)` which surprises me. If the **Person** in `ClassRoom(Person person)` is null, shouldn't `ClassRoom()` be called instead of `ClassRoom(Person person, string name)`?

Comment: `person == null ? null : person` is a nonsense operation. And what makes you think that your code would call different constructors here?

Comment: "*If the **Person** in `ClassRoom(Person person)` is null, shouldn't `ClassRoom()` be called instead of `ClassRoom(Person person, string name)`*" - no, `null` is still a valid value for `Person` so you are still invoking `Class(Person person)` constructor, you would have to explicitly call the non-parameter constructor (which ultimately you can't do at runtime, unless using reflection).

Comment: @James was about to write that but then realized...shouldn't that end in a StackOverflowException? If null is passed to ClassRoom(Person person), it'll call that constructor again and again and again. Not sure how it ends up in the other constructor?!

Comment: @SteffenWinkler - That constructor calls the two-argument constructor. The NRE happens when trying to acces `person.Name` in the chained call.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler no, what it will throw is an `NullReferenceException` because it tries to call into the overloaded `ClassRoom(Person person, string name)` constructor by passing `person.Name` as the parameter. However, if `person` is `null` (like it is in the example) then it will throw, there is no recursion here.

Comment: @Lee yeah, I don't get why it'd call the two-argument constructor. If person is null, it should call itself again.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler - Because it's providing two arguments - `this(person == null ? null : person, person.Name)`

Comment: oh. Read that wrong. Thank's for writing it out.

Answer (score 4):

> My goal with ClassRoom(Person person) is that, if the Person is null, ClassRoom() is called and if it's not null ClassRoom(Person person, string name) is called.

You can't do that, basically. You can't decide which constructor to chain to at execution time. Overload resolution is performed at *compile-time*, and that's what determines what you're chaining to. It's not clear why you'd expect your current code to do it anyway, but you can't do it at all.

Basically you should reconsider your design. Typically, it's a good idea for constructors with fewer parameters to call constructors with more parameters, passing in default values. For example:

```
protected ClassRoom() : this(null)
{
}

public ClassRoom(Person person)
    : this(person, person == null ? "" : person.Name)
{
}

public ClassRoom(Person person, string name)
{
    this.person = person;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: we should make this into a uservoice suggestion: depended types for .net :D

Answer (score 0):

If the intent here is to provide this null-checking functionality without having to do such a check every time you create a ClassRoom, you could try the following pattern instead:

```
public class ClassRoom
{
    public static ClassRoom CreateClassRoom(Person person = null)
    {
        if(person == null)
            return new ClassRoom();
        else 
            return new ClassRoom(person,person.Name);
    }

    private ClassRoom()
    {
    }
    private ClassRoom(Person person, string name)
    {
        //Not sure why you would do this, because you're setting it to what it already is.
        person.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then, to create a ClassRoom, instead do this:

```
var classRoom1 = ClassRoom.CreateClassRoom(new Person());
var classRoom2 = ClassRoom.CreateClassRoom(null);
var classRoom3 = ClassRoom.CreateClassRoom();
```